# Not recognizing the record type parameter of a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to test a newly created stored procedure in Oracle.

I added the stored procedure to the package and successfully compiled it. The input parameter is a record type.

This is the script:

```
SET serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  p_trlr_rec trailer%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    /* Call procedure within package, identifying schema if necessary */
    TMS_SL_SQL_TRAILER.PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO(p_trlr_rec);
END;
```

I get the error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO'

In the package file, the parameter is defined like this:

```
PROCEDURE PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO
(p_rec         IN OUT rectype_trailer);

PROCEDURE PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO
    (p_rec         IN OUT rectype_trailer);
```

I also tried adding the TYPE definition:

```
PROCEDURE PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO
    (p_rec         IN OUT rectype_trailer);
```

but I get the same error.

Why won't the script recognize the record definition?

Answer (score 1):

Well the script is recognizing your record definitions, both of them. The calling routine is passing a parameter of type "trailer%ROWTYPE" but your procedure is expecting a type of "rectype_trailer" Even if "rectype_trailer"  is defined elsewhere they are not the same; thus the error is wrong type of argument.

You need to change one of them to match the other. Assuming the rowtype definition is correct you need to change the procedure definition to

```
PROCEDURE PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO
(p_rec         IN OUT trailer%ROWTYPE);
```

In short the calling parameter definition must exactly match the called procedure definition.

Answer (score 1):

> `PROCEDURE PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO
>   (p_rec         IN OUT rectype_trailer);`

So for this to compile you must have declared that record type somewhere, hopefully in the specification of the package `TMS_SL_SQL_TRAILER`. So you simply need to reference that declaration in the calling code:

```
DECLARE
  p_trlr_rec TMS_SL_SQL_TRAILER.rectype_trailer;
BEGIN
    /* Call procedure within package, identifying schema if necessary */
    TMS_SL_SQL_TRAILER.PR_UPDATE_DUE_INFO(p_trlr_rec);
END;
```

Oracle PL/SQL strictly enforces data typing. Two different types with identical structures are two different types and the compiler regards them as incompatible. So the compiler hurls when it tries to parse your calling code even if `TMS_SL_SQL_TRAILER.rectype_trailer` is declared as being of `trailer%ROWTYPE`.